# changing label by clicking on button GTK C

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm new to making GUI using GTK+ and I'm using glade to build the GUI and I am trying to simply change label by clicking on a button here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

typedef struct {
GtkWidget *window1 ;
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *label1;
}AppWidgets;

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_button1_clicked(GtkButton *button,
                    gpointer user_data)
{
  AppWidgets * app = (AppWidgets *) user_data;
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(app->label1),"Hello World!");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

 GtkBuilder  *builder;
 AppWidgets  *app=g_slice_new(AppWidgets) ;
 GError  *err=NULL;

 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 builder = gtk_builder_new();
 gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "GUI", &err);

 #define appGET(xx) \
 app->xx=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,#xx))

 appGET(window1);
 appGET(button1);
 appGET(label1);


 gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, &app);
 g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));


 gtk_widget_show(app->window1);
 gtk_main ();
 return 0;
}
```

and here is my .glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="resizable">true</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">1000</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">none</property>
            <property name="focus_on_click">False</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

this code simply does nothing so what should i do to change the label text ?

Comment: the command im using:
    g++ -rdynamic  -o testGUI -Wall -g main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0)

Comment: 1) This information belongs into the question, not a comment. 2) You are compiling as C++. This is a different language which happens to share some syntax and grammar with C.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Olaf :yes i knew..but i am new here and couldnt find how to edit my question..
Paul Floyd : no errors the code compiles just fine but the label wont change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compiling your code, with:

```
gcc -o test main.c -rdynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-export-2.0`
```

Probably gmodule-export-2.0 will be included by GTK so may be redundant.

The result is that the label won't change and the error thrown to the console is:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

Which means that app->label1 isn't a GtkLabel.

So the problem is on signal connection:

```
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, &app);
```

Here you should change to:

```
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, app);
```

From the C API:

> void gtk_builder_connect_signals (GtkBuilder *builder,
>                                gpointer user_data);

Comment: Thanks that worked  i changed the command to the 1 you wrote and the signal connecting function and it worked